# jQuery each() finish outer function after the end of iterations

Tags: jquery, coffeescript, each

I have a function that needs to loop through all the select tags and the cheackboxes, take their name and value and then assign it to the "data" object. Here's the code

```
data_query:->      
  data = {}
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').each ->
    data[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).is(":checked")
  $('select').each ->
    data[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val()
  # console.log data
  return data
```

Result should be something like:

```
Object {select_one: "value", select_two: "value", ag_1: false, ag_2: true, ft_1: false, ft_2: false, bg_1: false}
```

But What I get at the end is:

```
Object {select_one: "value", select_two: "value", ag_1: false} #it gets only one checkbox
```

I understand the nature of callbacks and I know why it happens - the outer funcion ends before the end of the inner loops but I have no idea how to solve this

Thanks!

**Edit:** here is the HTML. Its just simple select tags and checkboxes

```
      <li><label for="ag_1"><input name="ag_1" type="checkbox" id="ag_1"> AG-1</label></li>
      <li><label for="ag_2"><input name="ag_2" type="checkbox" id="ag_2"> AG-2</label></li>
      <li><label for="ft_1"><input name="ft_1" type="checkbox" id="ft_1"> FT-1</label></li>
      <li><label for="ft_2"><input name="ft_2" type="checkbox" id="ft_2"> FT-2</label></li>
      <li><label for="bg_2"><input name="bg_1" type="checkbox" id="bg_2"> BG-1</label>    </li>

<!-- there's a bunch of these -->
<select name="select_one" id="select_one">
      <option value="">-- Select One --</option>
      <option value="ac_1">AC-1</option>
      <option value="ac_2">AC-2</option>
      <option value="ac_3">AC-3</option>
      <option value="ac_4">AC-4</option>
      <option value="ac_5">AC-5</option>
      <option value="ac_6">AC-6</option>
      <option value="ac_7">AC-7</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Can you show the `html`

Comment: Since `$.each` callbacks are executed synchronously, overwriting the closed over variables is not an issue here. The outer function does not end before the inner one

Comment: If I console.log inside the .each(), the data object gets all the name:values as expected, so why it gives only on checkbox when returning the data from the outer function?

Comment: weird... http://jsfiddle.net/2kMh8/

Comment: it stops iterating once false is evaluated. Try checking all boxes and you'll see what I mean

Comment: @JanDvorak Your fiddle returned returned only one checkbox. The select tags should have different names (i.e. different keys in the data object)

Comment: @zgr024 yep. That's it. Implicit return

Comment: So how do I override the implicit return? if false then continue ?

Comment: return something else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that CoffeeScript implictly returns the value you're assigning to the `data` property. Yet, the [jQuery `each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) does consider a return value of `false` as a `break`, and ends the loop. You have to return `undefined` "explicitly":

```
data = {}
console.log $('input[type="checkbox"]').each ->
  data[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).is(":checked")
  return
$('select').each ->
  data[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val()
  return
return data
```

([Demo at jsfiddle.org](http://jsfiddle.net/8zKNw/), [produced code](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3aobj%20%3D%20%0A%20%20data_query%3A-%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20data%20%3D%20%7B%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%24%28%27input%5Btype%3D%22checkbox%22%5D%27%29.each%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20data%5B%24%28this%29.attr%28%27name%27%29%5D%20%3D%20%24%28this%29.is%28%22%3Achecked%22%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20return%0A%20%20%20%20%24%28%27select%27%29.each%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20data%5B%24%28this%29.attr%28%27name%27%29%5D%20%3D%20%24%28this%29.val%28%29%23%20console.log%20data%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20return%0A%20%20%20%20return%20data%0A%0A%24%20-%3E%0A%20%20%24%28%22%23output%22%29.text%20JSON.stringify%20obj.data_query))